# Import functions from modules back and fort

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import, python-module

Hi I have problem with importing functions in my modules. I get error:

```
NameError: name 'main_menu' is not defined
```

I have 6 modules (main, menu, users, books, cars, etc)

In my **main.py** I have `from menu import *`

In my **menu.py** I have:

```
from users import *
from books import *
```

And now when I try to import function **main_menu()** from **menu.py** to my **users.py** I get that error.

I remembered that somehow I can't import functions back and forth from modules. But how can I call **main_menu()** function that is located in **menu.py** than?

My question really is, how can I import and call a function from other module if I already imported everything from my current module?

EDIT:

**main.py**

```
from menu import *


def login():

    x = str(input("Username:"))
    y = str(input("Password:"))

    if x == "admin" and y == "admin":
        main_menu()
    else:
        print('Wrong!')
login()
```

**menu.py**

```
from users import *

def main_menu():
    print("Welcome to main menu:")
    option = str(input("Enter option: "))
    if option == '1':
        all_users()
```

**users.py**

```
from menu import *

def all_users():
    allusers = ["Mike", "John", "Nick"]
    print(allusers)
    backtomenu = str(input("Back to main menu: (Y/N) "))
    if backtomenu == "Y":
        main_menu()
    elif backtomenu == "N":
        quit()
```

**ERROR:**

```
Username:admin
Password:admin
Welcome to main menu:
Enter option: 1
['Mike', 'John', 'Nick']
Back to main menu: (Y/N) Y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sm\Desktop\ss\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    login()
  File "C:\Users\Sm\Desktop\ss\main.py", line 10, in login
    main_menu()
  File "C:\Users\Sm\Desktop\ss\menu.py", line 7, in main_menu
    all_users()
  File "C:\Users\Sm\Desktop\ss\users.py", line 8, in all_users
    main_menu()
NameError: name 'main_menu' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: The error you provide doesn't match the function names you mention. Please edit and provide a [mcve] and error.

Comment: @JulienBernu is it okay now?

Comment: Instead of saying I do this, then I do that, please share the content of all the relevant scripts. With the little information you are sharing it's hard to tell if you are just forgetting an import or if that (maybe) missing import would create circular reference...

Comment: @JulienBernu Maybe its something with circular reference, but how can I fix it and make it work. Here, I provided everything. Thanks for helping. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a circular import between the `menu` and `users` modules. Since you're using `from module import *` syntax, it doesn't work out the way you intend. One of the modules is empty when you try to import all the names from it (since it's waiting on the other one to load). Exactly which module fails will depend on how external code first loads these modules.

A simple fix would be to use just the basic `import module` syntax instead of `from module import *` (wildcard imports are often a bad idea anyway, for reasons of namespace pollution).

So you could try:

**menu.py**:

```
import users

def main_menu():
    print("Welcome to main menu:")
    option = str(input("Enter option: "))
    if option == '1':
        users.all_users()
```

**users.py**:

```
import menu

def all_users():
    allusers = ["Mike", "John", "Nick"]
    print(allusers)
    backtomenu = str(input("Back to main menu: (Y/N) "))
    if backtomenu == "Y":
        menu.main_menu()
    elif backtomenu == "N":
        quit()
```

Many people will tell you that circular imports are a clear sign of bad design, and that you should always get rid of them. I tend not to come down so hard on them, since they can work just fine in Python if you get them right.

But in this case, it might make sense to simply combine some of your modules together. If you don't need namespace separation (which you clearly didn't, since you were using wildcard imports), you might as well put everything in the same file. Then you won't have any issues with circular imports, since you won't have any imports at all.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to combine something from your answer!